# Can someone help me solve this quadratic word problem?

Tags: functions

Grade 10 Quadratics word problem.

What is the rule of the function $f$ that has a range of $[-\infty ,4]$ and is a positive over the interval $[-1,3]$?

I am not sure of the steps to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica, create a function that has roots at the specified points, in this case, x=-1 and x=3, then choose the sign negative. Here is an example:

```
Plot[-(x + 1) (x - 3), {x, -5, 6}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this it might help you to think about what form the quadratic must have. Is $y=a x^2+b x+c$ useful or would writing things in terms of the 0's be more useful? ($y=c(x-a)(x-b)$)

Some helpful hints on this would be that you know when the function goes from being negative to being positive. (What does that tell you about the value of y at those points?)